# How to get out of this "loop" without any input indicating termination?

Tags: c++

This is an OJ problem.
**Description:** Get the sum of the input data.
**Input:** There are several lines of input, each line contains several integers, and each integer is separated by a single space. You need to get the sum of each line's integers.
**Output:** The sum of corresponding line.
**Sample input:**

```
100 200 4
45 45
```

**Sample output:**

```
304
90
```

And my code is as follows:

```
//time limit exceeded
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char a[500];
    while (true){
        gets_s(a);
        int len = strlen(a), sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len + 1; i++){
            if (a[i] == EOF)return 0;
            if (a[i] == ' ' || a[i] == '\0'){
                for (int j = i - 1; a[j] != ' '&&j >= 0; j--){
                    sum += (a[j] - '0')*pow(10, i - j - 1);
                }
                if (a[i] == '\0')break;
            }
        }
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I believe the problem lies in the program keep waiting for another input when there's no more lines to input. But how to solve this?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Use `std::getline()` in a loop until it returns `false`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry but I don't quite understand...

Comment: Maybe [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) helps.

Comment: This is much easier if you forget about C.

Comment: You're making this a bit complicated. http://ideone.com/nmA1WQ

Comment: There is nothing in your code that could possibly get you out of the `while(true)`. Maybe the `break` was meant to do so, but it breaks the `for` loop and not the `while` loop...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if (a[i] == EOF)` check doesn't make sense. When EOF is reached (or some error occurs), then `gets_s` doesn't indicate this by storing a magic value inside the buffer, it indicates it through the result. You can get rid of this `if` condition, and check `gets_s`'s result in the outer loop:

```
while (gets_s(a)) {
    ...
}
```